# Problems using ambhas package: statistics module has no cpdf attribute

Tags: python-3.x, statistics

I am trying to use the ambhas package for copulas and the method

```
 foo.generate_xy()
```

is not working.

This is error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    generate()
  File "C:/Users/Mypc/Desktop/sfsdf.py", line 19, in genera
    x1,y1 = foo.generate_xy()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\ambhas\copula.py", line 179, in     generate_xy
    self._inverse_cdf()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\ambhas\copula.py", line 256, in  _inverse_cdf
    x2, x1 = st.cpdf(self.X, kernel = 'Epanechnikov', n = 100)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cpdf'
```

Basically I checked the code in the ambhas module and it turns out it is trying to use a method from the statistics module (imported as st), st.cpdf() which I do not have in my statistics module.

How can I fix this problem?

Here is an example of the code working. This is the very same code I am trying to run through the generate() function:
https://code.google.com/p/ambhas/wiki/Cookbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AMBHAS code depends on [this](http://bonsai.hgc.jp/~mdehoon/software/python/Statistics) `statistics` module, not the "official" one that is now included in Python 3.4. Unfortunately, the module doesn't appear to have been updated in a while, and the latest Windows installer is for Python 3.2, so you'll need to build it from source. You can do this with [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), or by installing [Visual C++ 2010 Express](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9709949) ([here](http://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/12/21/compiling-python-extensions-on-windows/) is a blog post describing the process, but I haven't tried it myself so I don't know if it's completely accurate - YMMV).

Once you've compiled the extension, make sure you remove the `statistics` module you installed previously before running `python setup.py install`.

Comment: I have the statistics module in my 3.3 version however in does not contain that method.  Is the installation of the 3.4 version the only way?

Comment: @mickkk I'm doing some more research on this. Did you get your `statistics` module from [here](http://bonsai.hgc.jp/~mdehoon/software/python/Statistics)?

Comment: thanks, actually I got it from the official page https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html

Comment: I have installed `statistics` using the installer in python 3.2, but it's showing the error- `ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import`.

Comment: @lsr729 do you have `numpy` installed?